# List combining: x = [1,2,3], y = [10,20,30] ==> x_y = [[1,10], [2,20], [3,30]]

Tags: python, list, numpy

I've got two lists x and y.
Want to combine them in a way:

```
 x_y = [[x[0], y[0]], [x[1], y[1]]...].
```

The code I have is:

```
import numpy as np

x_ax = np.array(list(range(1, 101)))
y_ax = np.array(list(range(101,201)))

mixed = []
mini = []
for a, b in zip(x_ax, y_ax):
    mini = [a,b]
    mixed.append(mini)

print(mixed)
```

I am sure there are better ways to do it.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Try `list(zip(x,y))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do `np.stack`. This will return a 2D numpy array

```
np.stack([x_ax, y_ax]).T
```

Or you can use `zip`. This will return a list of tuples.

```
list(zip(x_ax,y_ax))
```

Comment: Better vote to close as dupe

Comment: will vote as well.